# Marionette how to render regions in Order

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js, marionette

Marionette is there a way to render regions in order? If one region needs a DOM element in another region. Right im now triggering an event to render it in order, but is there any better way to accomplish this?

```
regions: {
    offersTab: '#section-offers-tab',
    offersList: '#section-offers-list',
  },

onRender() {
      this.listenTo(app.channel, 'render:tabs', (opt) => {
        this.getRegion('offersTab').show(new OffersTabView());
      });

      //trigger "render:tabs" once offersList is attached to DOM
      this.getRegion('offersList').show(new OffersListView());

  },
```

Comment: Can you update question with some of the view structure you're referring to?

Comment: hi @Grafpaper10 , i have added a small snippet of what I am trying to achieve,

Comment: You can just have `#section-offers-tab` directly in the parent view.
If that is not possible and `#section-offers-list` must contain `#section-offers-tab`, then that is indicator that `OffersListView` should be rendering OffersTabView. Parent views should not be directly affecting child's DOM.

If this is not about DOM element relationship, but just about timing, then what you are doing now, or just an empty timeout etc will do